# Saving image from canvas in server through Jquery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, image, canvas

I am trying to store Canvas image to server through PHP I can see the file but it shows 0 bytes. Can you please help me to fix this issue.

Here is my code below:

**HTML:**

```
<img id="image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K..." />
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('.submit').unbind().click(function(){
var dataURL = $('#img').attr('src');
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "saveimage.php",
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  data: { 
   imgBase64: dataURL
  }
 });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$upload_dir = "../images/";
$img = $_POST['data'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = $upload_dir."image_name.png";
file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be **`$img = $_POST['imgBase64']`** 
**not** **`$img = $_POST['data']`** in your php

as your data *object* 's key name is **`imgBase64`** when sending the *ajax* post request